# MLE - Optimization with constraints as non-linear functions of the variables

Tags: r, optimization, constraints, mle

I have a problem with the following optimization problem. In particular, I would like to add the following constraint to the MLE problem: `(x - location)/scale > 0`. Without this constraint, the LL is `Inf` and the `L-BGFS-B` optimization gives the following error

```
library(PearsonDS)
x <- rpearsonIII(n=1000, shape = 5, location = 6, scale = 7)

dpearson3 <- function (x, shape, location, scale, log = FALSE) 
{
  gscale <- abs(scale)
  ssgn <- sign(scale)
  density <- dgamma(ssgn * (x - location), shape = shape, scale = gscale, log = log)

  return(density)

}

LL3 <- function(theta, x, display)
{
        shape <- as.numeric(theta[1])
        location <- as.numeric(theta[2])
        scale <- as.numeric(theta[3])

        tmp <- -sum(log(dpearson3(x, shape, location, scale, log = FALSE)))

        if (is.na(tmp)) +Inf else tmp
        if(display == 1){print(c(tmp, theta))}
        return(sum(tmp))
}

control.list <- list(maxit = 100000, factr=1e-12, fnscale = 1)

fit <- optim(par = param, 
               fn = LL3, 
               hessian = TRUE, 
               method = "L-BFGS-B",
               lower = c(0,-Inf,-Inf),
               upper = c(Inf,Inf,Inf),
               control = control.list,
               x = x, display = 1)
```

Assume that I start the search from 
`param <- c(100,1000,10)`, I get the following error

`Error in optim(par = param, fn = LL3, hessian = TRUE, method = "L-BFGS-B",  : 
  L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'`

How to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the MLE function to

```
LL3 <- function(theta, x, display){
  shape <- as.numeric(theta[1])
  location <- as.numeric(theta[2])
  scale <- as.numeric(theta[3])

  tmp <- -sum(log(dpearson3(x, shape, location, scale, log = FALSE)))

  if(min((x-location)/scale) < 0) tmp = + 100000000000 # I added this line
  if (is.na(tmp)) +Inf else tmp
  if(display == 1){print(c(tmp, theta))}
  return(tmp)
}
```

is the smartest thing I could find. In this way I avoid the `Inf` problem. Any better answer?